# Copy 2 array in a new one

Tags: java, arrays

What is the best way (elegant/efficient) to copy two arrays into a new one ?

Regards,

F

Comment: you should at least try to search a little bit before posting a question..

Comment: why down vote? stackoverflow answers questions that have to deal with programming

Answer (score 6):

My reputation doesn't allow me to comment on Adamski's answer, but there is an error on this line:

```
 System.arraycopy(src2, 0, dest, src1.length - 1, src2.length);
```

With *src1.length - 1* as an argument to *destPos*, you overwrite the last element copied from the *src1* array. In this case you overwrite the element on index 4, which is the 5th element of the array.

This code might be easier to understand:

```
    int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int[] array2 = { 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    int[] array3 = new int[ array1.length + array2.length ];

    System.arraycopy( array1, 0, array3, 0, array1.length );
    System.arraycopy( array2, 0, array3, array1.length, array2.length );

    for (int i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) {
        System.out.print( array3[i] + ", " );
    }
```

Comment: Noted - I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `System.arraycopy` takes advantage of the underlying hardware to perform the array copy as efficiently as possible.

In the context of the question you would need to call `System.arraycopy` twice; e.g.

```
int[] dest = new int[10];
int[] src1 = new int[5];
int[] src2 = new int[5];

// Populate source arrays with test data.
for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
  src1[i] = i;
  src2[i] = i + 100;
}

System.arraycopy(src1, 0, dest, 0, src1.length);
System.arraycopy(src2, 0, dest, src1.length, src2.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.arraycopy][1] as shown [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

[1]: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.Object, int, int)